# "COM target does not implement IDispatch" exception when opening Outlook.Contact

Tags: c#, outlook

My code is straightforward:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

private Outlook.ContactItem contact;

private void OutlookButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        contact = new Outlook.ContactItem((Outlook.ContactItem)((Button)sender).Tag);
        contact.Display();
```

The `Display()` line raises an exception related to `IDispatch`:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: COM target does not
>   implement IDispatch.

There is an Outlook contact object bound to the buttons tag, and the idea is that when the button is clicked it will open up to show them.

Outlook (the application) is not running. The above works fine the first time, but if I click on the same button a second time, the exception above is raised.

If tried using `NetOffice`, that gave me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create Outlook items using the class ctor. Instead, you need to use the [CreateItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869635(v=office.15).aspx) or [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865637(v=office.15).aspx) methods of the Application class.

Also the **Add** method of the Items class can be used to create new Outlook items.

Most probably you need to correct the code:

```
contact = (Outlook.ContactItem)((Button)sender).Tag);
contact.Display();
```

Anyway, I'd recommend storing the entry ID value in the tag instead. You can use the [GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class at any convinient time.

Comment: I modified my code to so that when all the contacts are pulled in, the contact Entry ID (String) and OutlookContact (Outlook.Contact) are added to my "OfficeContact" object. I have an observable collection of them. I also modified the code so that the Tag property of the buttin is boind to the EntryID. So now when thr button is clicked, I terate the observable collection, get a match for EntryID, and then try to Display() the Office.Contact object of my OfficeContact - I end up with the exact same error. So I think I'm closer...but "Display()" is still killing me.

Comment: foreach (OfficeContact aContact in mainWindow.outlookContacts.officeContacts)
                {
                    if (aContact.OutlookContactEntryID == ourContactEntryID)
                    {
                        aContact.OutlookContactObject.Display();
                    }
                }